# Make a static library instead of dynamic

Tags: makefile

I want to make static [XGBoost](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/blob/master/Makefile) library, but I'm failing at this easy task.

Firstly, I simply tried to take all `.o` files and via `ar rcs wrapper/libxgboostwrapper.a ./*` make static library, but I failed. In fact, when I'm making other stuff which depends on XGBoost it fails with errors: `undefined reference to XGBoosterFree`.

This function is defined in wrapper part and there is no file `wrapper/libxgboostwrapper.o`. So in order to make a static library firstly we have to create `wrapper/libxgboostwrapper.o`, secondly, run `ar rcs` on all needed `.o` files.

*How I modified Makefile*.

1. Firstly, I slightly changed names of some variables.

   ```
   ifeq ($(OS), Windows_NT)
     LIBRABIT = subtree/rabit/lib/librabit_empty.a
     DLIB = wrapper/xgboost_wrapper.dll
     SLIB = wrapper/xgboost_wrapper.lib
   else
     LIBRABIT = subtree/rabit/lib/librabit.a
     DLIB = wrapper/libxgboostwrapper.so
     SLIB = wrapper/libxgboostwrapper.a
   endif
   ```
2. Added new variable.

   ```
   WRAP = wrapper/libxgboostwrapper.o
   ```
3. Modified target.

   ```
   TARGET = $(BIN) $(OBJ) $(DLIB) $(SLIB) $(WRAP)
   ```
4. Added dependencies for `wrapper/libxgboostwrapper.o` exactly the same as for `wrapper/libxgboostwrapper.so`.

   ```
   wrapper/libxgboostwrapper.o: wrapper/xgboost_wrapper.cpp src/utils/*.h src/*.h src/learner/*.hpp src/learner/*.h  updater.o gbm.o io.o $(LIBRABIT) $(LIBDMLC)
   ```
5. After everything is done for `$(BIN)`, `$(MOCKBIN)`, `$(DLIB)`, I'm trying to compile (or make?) my `$(WRAP)`.

   ```
   $(WRAP) :
     $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -fPIC -o $@ $(filter %.cpp %.o %.c %.a %.cc, $^) $(LDFLAGS) $(DLLFLAGS)
   ```
6. After all this stuff finally I'm making `wrapper/libxgboostwrapper.a`.

   ```
   $(SLIB) : updater.o gbm.o io.o $(WRAP) $(LIBRABIT) $(LIBDMLC)
     ar rcs $@ $^
   ```

It fails at step 5 with errors like:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o(.debug_info): relocation 0 has invalid symbol index 10
```

What am I doing wrong? For me it seems like compilation `.so` and `.o` files shuld be the same except flag `-shared` is not used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may take a few iterations, since you seem to have a few misconceptions about how these files work.

**STEP 1:** First, let's compile a source file to produce an object file:

```
g++ -o wrapper/xgboostwrapper.o -c wrapper/xgboost_wrapper.cpp
```

(Don't call the object file "libxgboostwrapper.o". The "lib" prefix is for a library, the ".o" suffix is for an object file, when you use them both it's just confusing.)

**Do not proceed until that works.**

**STEP 2:** Write a rule in your makefile to do it:

```
wrapper/xgboostwrapper.o: wrapper/xgboost_wrapper.cpp
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<
```

**Do not proceed until that works.**

**STEP 3:** Figure out which header files it *actually needs*, and add those as prerequisites. (It's a bad idea to use wildcards to add *all existing* headers as prerequisites.):

```
wrapper/xgboostwrapper.o: wrapper/xgboost_wrapper.cpp src/utils/foo.h src/xgboost.h
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<
```

Try that much and tell us how it went, then we can proceed.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I solved my problems without your answer unfortunately! :)

Firstly I produced object file wrapper.o and then simply added all needed object files into one library.